How to match a text from the output which are coming from for loop - Angular/Javascript
I have an xml from which I got all the tag name by using for loop and other logic. Now I need to match a word 'author' from the output values coming from for loop in console. If any of the output values matches 'author' then need to put a condition. Below is the code
app.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'project';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let xmldata = "<bookstore><book>" +
      "<title>Everyday Italian</title>" +
      "<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>" +
      "<year>2005</year>" +
      "</book></bookstore>";
    var node = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmldata, "text/xml").documentElement;
    var nodes = node.querySelectorAll("*");
    // console.log(nodes[4].tagName)
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      var text = null;
      if (nodes[i].childNodes.length == 1 && nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeType == 3) //if nodeType == text node
        text = nodes[i].textContent; //get text of the node
      //  console.log("TageName : ", nodes[i].tagName, ", Text : ", text);
      console.log(nodes[i].tagName)
    }
  }
}
   


I feel the best bet is transform your XML in a json object. You can see how (only work for simples XML) in this link, stackblitz in another one

We can convert the output to an array, then use filter to filter out all the authors, then using map we can get only the inner texts.
Full code
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  title = 'project';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let xmldata =
      '<bookstore><book>' +
      '<title>Everyday Italian</title>' +
      '<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>' +
      '<year>2005</year>' +
      '</book><book>' +
      '<title>Everyday Italian</title>' +
      '<author>Giada De Laurentiis1</author>' +
      '<year>2005</year>' +
      '</book><book>' +
      '<title>Everyday Italian</title>' +
      '<author>Giada De Laurentiis2</author>' +
      '<year>2005</year>' +
      '</book></bookstore>';
    var node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
      xmldata,
      'text/xml'
    ).documentElement;
    var nodes = node.querySelectorAll('*');
    // convert nodes to an array, then filter out authors and use map
    // to get only the specified property needed into the output array!
    const requiredData = Array.prototype.slice
      .call(nodes, 0)
      .filter((x: any) => x.nodeName === 'author')
      .map((x: any) => x.textContent);
    console.log(requiredData);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
